# Add button to right side of header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to add an icon button to the right side of my header in jQuery mobile.
I'm having trouble with the automatic left positioning.

Here's my header:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
     <h1>Resultaten</h1>
     <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconshadow="false"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" data-transition="slide"
        data-iconpos="notext">home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `class="ui-btn-right"` or add a class `ui-btn-right` in `<a>`

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
     <h1>Resultaten</h1>
     <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconshadow="false"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" data-transition="slide"
        data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right">home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I exactly use the same class but the link is still in the left side, any thoughts why ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple buttons that you want to align to the right using the `class="ui-btn-right"` in `<a>` will place all the buttons on top of each other. Instead you can just wrap a div around it and float to the right.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1>Resultaten</h1>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconshadow="false"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" data-transition="slide"
        data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right">btn 1</a>
        <a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconshadow="false"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" data-transition="slide"
        data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right">btn 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a data attribute in jQuery Mobile ver 1.2+, you can use `data-iconpos="right"`.

```
<a href="#Home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-iconshadow="false"
    data-direction="reverse" onclick="empty()" data-transition="slide"
    data-iconpos="notext">home</a>
```

[Official Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html)